# Python Sklearn: Understanding of d-tree Output for Categorical Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am learning Python *Scikit-learn*.

I have recently implemented `d-tree` on a problem set. The data set has all the categorical features, and unlike R, Python requires dummy coding of categorical variables.

I performed the dummy coding of all the categorical variables using the following code:

```
col_names =['city_name','signup_os','signup_channel']
df_with_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df2, columns = col_names)
```

The dummy encoding created new columns based on the number of factors that each column has and then substituted the values with 0 and 1:

[image]

I have created a `d-tree` algorithm on this new dataframe, but what making me confused is the output.

The `d-tree` method has been able to come up with node values of **.5** for the dummy coded columns:

[image]

How do I interpret the output? What is the significance of value `sign_up_os_windows <=.5`? How should I convert this back to the original variable?

Please help me with your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is not a problem that `DT` classifier represents a binary categorical variable as a float **0.5**. The condition `signup_os_ios_web <= 0.5` is the same as `signup_os_ios_web == 0.0`;
- The algorithm does not internally convert inputs.

Let me assume that **0** states 'NO' and **1** states 'YES'. Consider in your case the first node indicating to `signup_os_ios_web`:

- If the answer is 'NO' (`signup_os_ios_web <= 0.5` and therefore equals to 0), then it proceeds to its child, notably, `Eagerness`;
- If the latter is also 'NO', then the algorithm goes down the tree, reaching your `signup_os_windows` binary dummy... And so on.

Consider **0.5** as a simple medium threshold or a center between **0** and **1** which basically divides 'YES' and 'NO' into two possible even occurences.

---

### Example

Let us look at the shortened titanic dataset consisting of 22 samples. `X` looks like the following:

```
Indexer          (0)  (1)    (2)      (3)
PassengerID    Pclass Sex    Age      Fare
1                 3    1    22.00    7.2500
2                 1    0    38.00   71.2833
3                 3    0    26.00    7.9250
4                 1    0    35.00   53.1000
5                 3    1    35.00    8.0500
```

As you can see, the `Sex` column is a binary categorical variable with an index equal to 1.

`y` is an array representing if a person survived or not. If we print out the first 5 samples, we will receive:

> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

Which means that the first 5 people taken from this variable could not make it.

Okay, after we have fitted the `DT` classifier, we may create a graph out of it to see the tree structure more thoroughly (I have used `export_graphviz` to achieve that):

[image]

The first node indicates a gender of a given sample, the index **1** relates to the column named `Sex` as presented above. The column `PassengerID` is just an indexer of `X` dataframe.

You can also see that the condition is similar to yours, as the threshold equals to **0.5**. You may read it as:

> *if gender is female (if `Sex <= 0.5` which makes it automatically equal to 0), proceed to the left node*.

I hope that clarifies.

Comment: Thank you !! This was helpful.